# No se me cambia de color la caja

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function cambiarColor(color){
                color = document.getElementById("parte1").style.backgroundColor;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<!--CÓDIGO HTML-->
```

> Quiero cambiar el color de la caja al mover el ratón sobre ella

```
    <div id="parte1" onmouseover="cambiarColor('white');" onmouseout="cambiarColor('green');">texto</div>
```

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo ahí en tu método es decir que tu color, que le pasas por parámetros,  es el de la caja input, cuando debería ser al revés.

Comment: Para div cómo sería entonces?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tú estás haciendo es obtener el parámetro *color* para luego sobrescribirlo por el obtenido de la propiedad del div.

Bastaría que iguales la propiedad que quieres cambiar con el parámetro *color*. En este caso el `backgroundColor.

```js
function cambiarColor(color){
  document.getElementById("parte1").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<div id="parte1" onmouseover="cambiarColor('white');" onmouseout="cambiarColor('green');">texto</div>
```